# Mod_wsgi https Error Connection Refused

Tags: django, apache, ssl, https, mod-wsgi

My team is developing a REST API to support an iPhone app using Django's REST Framework. It has come time for us to switch from hosting via the development WSGI interface to the mod_wsgi apache interface. We've decided to use mod_wsgi-httpd as the Apache instance.

**We cannot get mod_wsgi to host over HTTPS.**

We've included mod_wsgi in our django application settings file (settings.py)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'sslserver',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'mod_wsgi.server',
)
```

And can successfully launch the mod_wsgi server using this command:

> python manage.py runmodwsgi --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --https-port 8001 --ssl-certificate /path/to/cert/and/key

The HTTP server works wonderfully. All of our HTTP only API methods listen and respond as expected. The HTTPS side is not cooperating. When attempting to access an HTTPS only method the **connection is refused**.

For example when attempting to connect to the method using Google Chrome...

> https://ipaddress:8001/ldapauth/       (ldapauth is an HTTPS method)

Chrome spits back...
[image]

Similarly requests formed in client-side Swift have connections refused.

Normally I would think this is a more fundamental issue, however our success in using the development WSGI sslserver (also in project's settings.py INSTALLED_APPS) makes me think this is an issue with mod_wsgi or mod_wsgi-httpd. Using this command we can host our API over SSL with successful requests/responses:

> python manage.py runsslserver 0.0.0.0:8001 --key /path/to/key --cert /path/to/cert

Any ideas what I could have missed in configuring mod_wsgi or mod_wsgi-httpd? Thanks so much for any help, go SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `--server-name` option with the name of the site it is accessible as using the https address. This should match the name the SSL certificates have been set up with.

```
python manage.py runmodwsgi --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --https-port 8001 --ssl-certificate /path/to/cert/and/key --server-name host.example.com
```

You would then access it using the URL with the FQDN:

```
https://host.example.com:8001
```

If you want to be able to access it from localhost (same system) without needing to provide a FQDN host name, you would use the `--allow-localhost` option.

```
python manage.py runmodwsgi --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --https-port 8001 --ssl-certificate /path/to/cert/and/key --server-name host.example.com --allow-localhost
```

With the latter, even if using an official certificate for the hostname, you will get the browser warning about certificate not matching. For command line HTTP tools like wget and curl you would have to tell them it is an insecure site in these cases.

It is because it is going against how HTTPS and SSL certificates would normally be used, access by name other than the proper server name is only allowed from localhost for testing purposes.

In short, when using HTTPS, you should really always be using a proper host name and not an IP address when accessing the site. If necessary you can create a dummy host mapping in host service file for your system.

For example, in a `/etc/hosts` file you could add:

```
127.0.0.1       host.example.com
```

For further information it is recommended that you use the mod_wsgi mailing list. I don't as a habit hang out here or answer questions about mod_wsgi here any more and it was by chance this question came to my attention.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This was exactly the problem. Gotta make sure mod_wsgi is aware of the server name.