# Apache - Error 403 Forbidden when deploying Django app

Tags: python, django, apache, centos

I am trying to deploy my Django application in Apache but it is impossible. When I enter the url it says 403 Forbidden and nothing happens.

I have tried watching many tutorials but have not been able to fix my error. I'm using CentOS 7.

This is my site.com.conf => /usr/local/apache/conf.d/vhost/myproject.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost myprojectIP:8181>
    ServerName myproject.com
    ServerAlias www.myproject.com
    ServerAdmin myproject@myproject.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myproject
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/public_html/cgi-bin/

    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "^https$" HTTPS=on
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir disabled
        UserDir enabled admin
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
        SuexecUserGroup admin admin
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup admin admin
        suPHP_ConfigPath /home/admin
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid admin admin
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule itk.c>
        AssignUserID admin admin
    </IfModule>

  <Directory /var/www/html/myproject>    
        Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        SSLRequireSSL
    </Directory> 

    <Directory /var/www/html/venv>
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /static /var/www/html/myproject/templates/static   
    <Directory /home/admin/public_html/myproject/templates/static>  
        Require all granted 
    </Directory> 
  
    WSGIProcessGroup remesas 
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myproject/remesas/wsgi.py
  
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my site.com.ssl.conf => /usr/local/apache/conf.d/vhost/myproject.com.ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost myprojectIP:8443>
    ServerName myproject.com
    ServerAlias www.myproject.com
    ServerAdmin myproject@myproject.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myproject
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/public_html/cgi-bin/

   #SSL CONFIGURE HERE

   ####################

    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir disabled
        UserDir enabled admin
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
        SuexecUserGroup admin admin
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup admin admin
        suPHP_ConfigPath /home/admin
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid admin admin
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule itk.c>
        AssignUserID admin admin
    </IfModule>

  <Directory /var/www/html/myproject>    
        Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        SSLRequireSSL
    </Directory> 

    <Directory /var/www/html/venv>
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /static /var/www/html/myproject/templates/static   
    <Directory /home/admin/public_html/myproject/templates/static>  
        Require all granted 
    </Directory> 
  
    WSGIDaemonProcess remesas python-path=/var/www/html/myproject:/var/www/html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages 
    WSGIProcessGroup remesas 
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myproject/remesas/wsgi.py
  

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is insecure to deploy app at /var/www/html directory, 'cause it is a default apache folder. Check your apache logs (error.log) and django folder permissions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll change it. The apache log says: [Thu Sep 03 19:20:58.607354 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 5064:tid 140321504012032] [client 149.202.67.223:56256] AH02219: access to /var/www/html/myproject/remesas/wsgi.py failed, reason: SSL connection required

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822405/mod-wsgi-https-error-connection-refused, try this. I think that you haven't provided SSL in WSGI, idk

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 common error about this, check these:

- Incorrect file or folder permissions
- Incorrect settings in the
  .htaccess file

check your url path,  Permission and privileges